# If $x \geq C$, where $C > 0$ is a constant, then what is the least upper bound for $\dfrac{2x}{x + 1}$?

Tags: functions, inequality

The title says it all.

Since
$$f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x + 1} = 2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right),$$
then because $x \geq C$ where $C > 0$, an upper bound is given by
$$\dfrac{2x}{x + 1} < 2.$$

Note that the lower bound is equivalent to
$$x \geq C \iff x + 1 \geq C + 1 \iff \dfrac{1}{x + 1} \leq \dfrac{1}{C + 1}$$ $$\iff 2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right) \geq 2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{C + 1}\right),$$
so that if $2 - \varepsilon$ is an upper bound for $f(x)$ ($\varepsilon > 0$), then $\varepsilon$ satisfies the inequality
$$2 - \varepsilon \geq f(x) \geq 2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{C + 1}\right) \implies 0 < \varepsilon < \dfrac{2}{C + 1}.$$

My question is essentially whether we can do better than this.

Comment: It has maxima at $2$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, I agree.  Which brings me to my question:  Is the maximum of $2$ for
$$f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x + 1}$$
also its least upper bound?

Comment: Yes and the maxims is at x equal to $\infty$ when you divide denominator by x in numerator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
x&\ge C \\
f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{x + 1} &= 2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right)\\
x&\in [C,\infty)\\
x+1&\in[C+1, \infty)\\
\frac{1}{x+1}&\in\Bigg(0,\frac{1}{C+1}\Bigg]\\
1-\frac{1}{x+1}&\in \Bigg[1-\frac{1}{C+1}, 1\Bigg)\\
\dfrac{2x}{x + 1} = 2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right)&\in\Bigg[\frac{2C}{C+1}, 2\Bigg)\\
\end{align*}

So you have $$\frac{2C}{C+1}\le f(x) < 2$$

**Alternative:**
Since you have already (and correctly) found the lower bound we'll focus on the upper bound. We know that the function is monotonic, since 
$$f'(x) = \frac{2}{(x+1)^2} > 0$$

Hence, we know that the function attains it's maximum (if any) as $x\to \infty$.

Hence we find $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x}{x+1} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{x}} = \fbox{2}$$

Hence, $f(x)<2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer, Aritra!  =)

Answer (score 0):

rewrite $f(x)$ in the form $$\frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$ and consider the cases $$x>0$$ or $$x<0$$

Comment: Do I still need to consider the case $x < 0$?  I already know that $x \geq C$ and $C > 0$, so that $x > 0$ follows by transitivity.

Comment: Additionally, the derivative satisfies
$$\dfrac{d}{dx} f(x) = \dfrac{2}{(x + 1)^2} > 0,$$
so that $f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: yes this is ok ,take a look at the graph of $f(x)$